# Merge content of document libraries using import-spweb?

Tags: 2013, migration

Is is possible to merge a document library with another library in another site using import-spweb?

We have a source document library called `/site/wiki/Shared%20Documents`
We also have a destination document library called `/site/Shared%20Documents`
We want to merge the contents of the two libraries into the destination library

We tried this:

```
export-spweb $sourceWebFullUrl -ItemUrl ($sourceListName) -IncludeUserSecurity -IncludeVersions All -path ($tempFilePath) -nologfile -force
import-spweb $destinationWebFullUrl -IncludeUserSecurity -path ($tempFilePath) -nologfile -force
```

But it fails:

```
import-spweb : A list, survey, discussion board, or document library with the specified title already exists in this Web site.
Please choose another title.
```

It seems that we can merge image and wiki page libraries this way but not document libraries... This post suggests we need a third party tool:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59476/merging-document-library-from-one-site-collection-to-a-document-library-in-a-sep

Is this possible OOTB? Is there a better way to merge document libraries without buying AvePoint etc?

Answer (score 1):

You could open both document libraries in Windows Explorer (you can do so with Internet Explorer from the ribbon) and the drag files from one library to the other...

Comment: There are thousands of these document libraries unfortunately

Comment: The third-party tools are probably your best bet.  Alternatively you could use PowerShell to download and upload the files in bulk.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rcormier/archive/2013/03/30/how-to-perform-bulk-downloads-of-files-in-sharepoint.aspx for exporting.  For upload: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/10/bulk-upload-files-to-sharepoint-using-powershell.html